# Interpreter that ignores leading >>> characters and ellipsis

Tags: python, ide, interpreter

I am studying some examples in a tutorial where there are a lot of leading >>> characters and ellipsis in the text. This makes it hard to cut and paste into the IPython interpreter since it doesn't like these strings.

Is there another interpreter I could use that will appropriately ignore and interpret these leading terms?

For example, I cannot paste the following directly into the interpreter:

```
>>> d = dict(x.__array_interface__)
>>> d['shape'] = (3, 2, 5)
>>> d['strides'] = (20, 20, 4)

>>> class Arr:
...     __array_interface__ = d
...     base = x
```

Comment: Then write a Python script which can clean it up. Do not kill a fly with a bazooka.

Comment: Try holding down alt, then dragging to select the first four columns, then deleting them.

Comment: paste it into a text editor that has vertical selection and remove those extra columns.

Comment: Also, lots of typing makes you smarter.

Comment: What I personally do, is paste the code into a Vim buffer and execute `<ESC>:%s/>>>//`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[IPython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/) can do this (look at the %paste magic command)

Answer (score 0):

In any case, a way to clean up such stuff by python code:

```
import re
matcher= re.compile("(?m)^[.>]{3} ")
def cleanup(text):
    return matcher.sub('', text)
```

Example use:

```
>>> print (cleanup(""">>> d = dict(x.__array_interface__)
>>> d['shape'] = (3, 2, 5)
>>> d['strides'] = (20, 20, 4)

>>> class Arr:
...     __array_interface__ = d
...     base = x"""))
```